# how to display interactive charts using flash builder

Tags: flash-builder

Hi
I have to display dashboard using flash builder. May i know some examples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Download the the samples from this page:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html

Or look at them online at: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/

Select Data visualization on the left, and look at all the chart samples.

Also look here: Visit http://flex.amcharts.com

Some of the code looks like this:

```
<fx:Style> 
    @font-face 
    {
        src: url("../assets/tahoma.ttf");
        fontFamily: "Tahoma";
        embedAsCFF: false;
        unicode-range:
            U+0020-U+0040, /* Punctuation, Numbers */
            U+0041-U+005A, /* Upper-Case A-Z */
            U+005B-U+0060, /* Punctuation and Symbols */
            U+0061-U+007A, /* Lower-Case a-z */
            U+007B-U+007E; /* Punctuation and Symbols */            
    }  

    .MyTextStyle 
    { 
        font-family: Tahoma; 
    }

</fx:Style> 

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;

        [Bindable]private var chartData:Array = [{country:"USA",visits:4252},{country:"China",visits:1882},{country:"Japan",visits:1809},{country:"Germany",visits:1322},{country:"UK",visits:1122},{country:"France",visits:1114},{country:"India",visits:984},{country:"Spain",visits:711},{country:"Netherlands",visits:665},{country:"Russia",visits:580},{country:"South Korea",visits:443},{country:"Canada",visits:441},{country:"Brazil",visits:395},{country:"Italy",visits:386},{country:"Australia",visits:384},{country:"Taiwan",visits:338},{country:"Poland",visits:328}];

        [Bindable]private var shadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(2,45,0,0.5);

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%">
    <amcharts:AmPieChart
        styleName="MyTextStyle"
        width="50%"
        height="100%"
        dataProvider="{chartData}"
        valueField="visits"
        titleField="country"
        angle="5"
        depth3D="5"
        innerRadius="10"
        groupPercent="3"
        gradient="radial"
        filters="{[shadow]}"
        startDuration="1.5"
        startRadius="100"
        marginLeft="0"
        marginRight="0"
        labelWidth="100">

        <amcharts:balloon>
            <amcharts:AmBalloon cornerRadius="10" borderThickness="2" borderColor="#FFFFFF" borderAlpha="1"/>                
        </amcharts:balloon>

    </amcharts:AmPieChart>

    <amcharts:AmSerialChart 
        styleName="MyTextStyle"
        width="50%"
        height="100%"
        dataProvider="{chartData}"
        categoryField="country"
        startDuration="1"
        angle="30"
        depth3D="15">
        <amcharts:categoryAxis>
            <amcharts:CategoryAxis gridCount="{chartData.length}" labelRotation="90"/>
        </amcharts:categoryAxis>
        <amcharts:graphs>
            <amcharts:AmGraph balloonText="[[category]]: [[value]]" id="g0" valueField="visits" type="column" lineAlpha="0" fillAlphas="[0.8]"/>                        
        </amcharts:graphs>
        <amcharts:balloon>
            <amcharts:AmBalloon cornerRadius="10" borderThickness="2" borderColor="#FFFFFF" borderAlpha="1"/>                
        </amcharts:balloon>    
        <amcharts:chartCursor>
            <amcharts:ChartCursor zoomable="false" cursorAlpha="0" categoryBalloonEnabled="false"/>                    
        </amcharts:chartCursor>    
    </amcharts:AmSerialChart>
</s:HGroup>
```